# Subset dataframe based on condition if column value has string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to keep rows in the dataframe if, in a cluster of records, the column value starts with a specified string meeting two conditions. This code works in one part of my program, but here it returns an empty dataframe. I'm not sure if it is because of the groupby or some other issue.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ClusterId': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'LastName': ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Smith', 'Roe'], 'FirstName': ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Edna'], 'City': ['Denver', 'Boston', 'Denver', 'Boulder']})

final_set = []
diff_records = df.groupby('ClusterId', as_index=False)        
for group, frame in diff_records:
    original_record = pd.DataFrame(frame.head(1))
    
    blocking_last_name = (original_record['LastName'].astype(str).str[:3].to_string()) 
    blocking_first_name = (original_record['FirstName'].astype(str).str[:3].to_string()) 
    blocking_city = (original_record['City'].astype(str).str[:3].to_string())   

    frame = frame[(frame['LastName'].str.startswith(blocking_lastname) & frame['City'].str.startswith(blocking_city)) |
    (frame['FirstName'].str.startswith(blocking_first_name) & frame['City'].str.startswith(blocking_city)) ]
```

The output would look like this, dropping Edna Roe from Boulder in Cluster 0 because it does not meet the criteria of matching to Joe and Mike Smith from Denver.

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'ClusterId': [0, 1, 0], 'LastName': ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Smith'], 'FirstName': ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Mike'], 'City': ['Denver', 'Boston', 'Denver']})
```

This is the solution that I used based on logic provided below.

```
final_set = []
diff_records = predict_list.groupby('ClusterId', as_index=False)        
    for group, frame in diff_records:
        frame = frame.loc[(frame['FirstName'].str[:3] == frame.head(1).FirstName.str[:3].iloc[0]) & (frame['City'].str[:3] == frame.head(1).City.str[:3].iloc[0]) | 
                              (frame['LastName'].str[:3] == frame.head(1).LastName.str[:3].iloc[0]) &  (frame['City'].str[:3] == frame.head(1).City.str[:4].iloc[0]) ]
                              
        final_set.append(frame)
final_set = pd.concat(final_set)
```

Comment: could you please show what the desired for this example should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your expected output I cannot fully validate.

- same approach but using `apply()` to do looping
- cleanup of multi-index with `droplevel()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ClusterId': [0, 1, 0], 'LastName': ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Smith'], 'FirstName': ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Mike'], 'City': ['Denver', 'Boston', 'Denver']})

def f(d):
    return d.loc[(d.LastName.str[:3] == d.head(1).LastName.str[:3].iloc[0]) 
                & (d.FirstName.str[:3] == d.head(1).FirstName.str[:3].iloc[0]) 
                & (d.City.str[:3] == d.head(1).City.str[:3].iloc[0]) 
                ]

df.groupby("ClusterId", as_index=False).apply(f).droplevel(1,0)
```

#### output

|  | ClusterId | LastName | FirstName | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Smith | Joe | Denver |
| 1 | 1 | Jones | Mike | Boston |

Comment: this is a slick general approach to similar problems +1

Comment: I added the desired output. I had to modify the original dataframe to illustrate what I expect to happen.

Comment: I tried this solution but got an error, "first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: I ended up using the following code but marked yours as correct because I used your logic.

Comment: odd that error,  in this calling context d is a dataframe.  What pandas version are you using? I'm using 1.2.4